# FIR filter not eliminating out of band noise?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, highpass-filter

I have a simple FIR filter that should eliminate all lower frequencies:

`H = zeros(60,1);
H(30:end) = 1+1i;
H = [H;conj(flipud(H(2:end)))]; % double sided
h= ifft(H);`

Then I assign a sample time to generate a time vector:

`dT = 0.002;
Tspan = dT*length(h);
dF = 1/Tspan;`

Here my nyquist is 250Hz.  So the filter should eliminate everything below 125Hz.

I generate a signal at 15Hz, and convolve it with the filter coefficients.

```
t = 0:dT:5;
x = cos(2*pi*15*t);
```

But, I get an output signal that clearly does not have the 15Hz eliminated:

Input signal above, response signal below
[image: Input signal above, response signal below]

Below is the FIR filter (plotted single sided):
[image: filter]

Does it look like my convolution algorithm is incorrect? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by an **fftshift** of the impulse response, as this line shows:

```
h = fftshift( real( ifft(H)) );
```

now it should work.

**NOTE** that there will be a transient of length about $60$ samples (half the linear phase FIR filter length) at the beginning of the convolution output, after which the steady state result emerges...

Comment: fftshift is usually applied to frequency domain FFTs...it gets applied to an impulse response here?  Thanks,Raman

Comment: @ramansridharan in this example all I wanted to do was to **circulate** the impulse response so that its peak comes to the middle (to its supposed place). So I used (or abused) fftshift for that purpose... it's similar to adding phase to the frequency samples.

Comment: @ramansridharan the frequency domain equivalent would be: `h = real( ifft( exp(-j*(2*pi/119)*59*[0:118]').*H2 ))`

Comment: Why would adding a phase shift change the amplitude response of the filter?

Comment: @ramansridharan because time- and frequency domain are linked: what you call "phase shift" is actually a modulation with a complex sinusoid, and corresponds to a cyclic time shift, exactly as Fat32 said. It's the same thing!

Comment: @ramansridharan when you obtained your impulse response from the frequency samples of H, you should also consider the fact that any (implied) noncausal part of it is reflected circularly at the end of the h[n] due to DFT properties. You should take this into account and correct it by a shift to right. By the way, your filter at passband H = 1+j is not linear phase, why do you use it ?